# Javascript - passing a file across windows in IE

Tags: javascript, file, internet-explorer, input, window

I have one browser window with an `<input type="file">`. When the user clicks a button on that page, it opens a new popup window to start an upload of the file, essentially as below:

```
var myFile = inputElement.files[0];
var newWindow = window.open('/popup');

. . . wait for popup to load

newWindow.popupFile = myFile;
```

The popup window then starts an upload of its `window.popupFile`.

This works as expected in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer. In IE11, logging `myFile` shows an `[object File]`. Once passed to the new window, `popupFile` is of type `[object Object]` and the upload fails, that object having apparently been stripped of its actual file data and File constructor.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to accomplish this in IE?

Comment: Can you use dev tools to break on the second line above and inspect the myFile object? Does it have any member fields filled in?

Comment: Sure, it's got name, size, lastModifiedDate, and type. All are filled in correctly, except type which is an empty string. It's also got a `FilePrototype` \_\_proto__ and a `File` constructor.

Comment: Once it arrives in the popup window, it's an object with all the same fields, but it no longer has the prototype or the constructor.

Comment: this is odd. I dont have an ie11 machine to test with at the moment but I have not had problems with newer versions of ie in the past.